Young adult novel featuring sci-fi agriculture, class struggles, and possibly cloning
I read this book 2010-2011 in an 8th grade English class. Certain elements of the story stick out strongly in my mind, but the plot is very scattered. Here are the details I remember.
The story follows a young man/boy. He is a member of some kind of group of other boys his age, and these groups are overseen by an older leader. The main character remarks that "if there are 10 of us for every leader, surely we can't all become leaders" in response to another boy who expects to become a leader one day.
They are somehow dealing with or working on (possibly slaves) some type of agricultural product. I think it had something to do with algae. I recall the technology seeming Sci-fi, and the world seeming like far-future earth (post some kind of climate disaster).
I have a vague recollection that the main character's (and/or other prominent characters) name(s) was Hispanic.
The plot of the story somehow revolves around the main characters attempt to escape this plantation he's on.
The last thing I remember is that cloning may feature in the story. The main character is possibly a clone.
I also recall a trip along the Colorado river taking place.

This kind of setting is common, but it reminded me of The Awakening Water:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/186038/48874 — although the later details in the question don't necessarily match.

@Buzz thank you; that is certainly similar but assuredly not the story I am looking for. No creature or aliens. I am also confident it takes place in the Americas: I've just recalled there is a voyage along the Colorado river.

Could it be Devil on My Back by Monica Hughes? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192684/novel-with-a-class-of-lords-with-external-databank-type-neural-implants Not the Colorado river from memory, but boy escapes a high-tech society after slave/servant revolt, travels down a river and then learns agriculture/humility from people outside.

I found the answer to this almost immediately after I posted the question, but was curious if anyone would post an answer. I actually posted my question into chatGPT and it produced the correct answer.
The book is The House of the Scorpion.
It follows a young boy named Matteo Alacran who is a clone of a drug lord named El Patron. Upon learning that he was created as a bespoke organ donor (and the sudden decline in health of El Patron) he flees the estate. He happens upon some dogmatic plankton farmers (called the 'Lost Boys') that feature the leadership dynamic I mentioned. He then leads the boys in a rebellion. The boys are rescued by a shrimp harvester boat that takes them to safety along the Colorado River.
There are further plot points and even a sequel. The novels are written by Nancy Farmer and were well received.

FWIW, as soon as I saw the title of your post (when it bumped back to the list of active posts just now after you answered), this book was the one I immediately thought of.

Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

@FuzzyBoots , seems a bit like saying 'bless you' to my own sneeze, but I understand the need.  Thank you for the reminder.
